# How to access form object with two-way-binding in angular directive without isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As titled, given the following simple example:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <button my-directive-test="myForm">Hello</button>
</form>

app.directive('my-directive-test', function() {
 return {
   restrict:'A',
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       // How to get scope.myForm.$submitted, scope.myForm.$errors without isolated scope?
   })
 };
});
```

Currently what I have been doing is:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <button my-directive-test="{{myForm.$submitted}}">Hello</button>
</form>

app.directive('my-directive-test', function() {
 return {
   restrict:'A',
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
     scope.formSubmitted = scope.$eval(attrs.myDirectiveTest);
     if (scope.formSubmitted) {
     } else {
     }
   })
 };
});
```

But what I would like to achieve is:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <button my-directive-test="myForm">Hello</button>
</form>

app.directive('my-directive-test', function() {
 return {
   restrict:'A',
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
     if (scope.myForm.$submitted) {
     } else {
     }
   })
 };
});
```

But so far I haven't found a way to bind the form object in my directive.

Comment: Why don't you want to use isolate scope?

Comment: Angular doesn't allow multiple directives on the same element if more than one of them uses isolate scope, see http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2729-don-t-blindly-isolate-all-the-scopes-in-angularjs-directives.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When not using isolated scope, the directive scope is the same as the "parent" element's scope.  So this will work:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <button my-directive-test="myForm">Hello</button>
</form>

app.directive('myDirectiveTest', function() {
 return {
   restrict:'A',
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
     if (scope[attrs.myDirectiveTest].$submitted) {
     } else {
     }
   })
 };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
app.directive('my-directive-test', function() {
return {
  restrict:'A',
  scope: { someVal: '='}
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   if (scope.someVal) {
    } else {
   }
  })
 };
});
```

and in html

```
<button my-directive-test myForm="someVal">Hello</button>
```

someVal can be $scope.myForm.$submitted or any other value.

more detail about isolate scope : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Thats isolated scope, I am trying to find a way to do so without isolated scope

Comment: my mistake, i though you want to use isolated scope, so you want to have the scope shared with controller ,i.e using controller scope ?

Comment: I might have to if I have no other choices. But I am hoping the directive can be easily reuse in all other views, so if controller is involved which means anyone else using this directive will need to remember to handle it in controller as well.

Comment: if that the case then you want to pass the object that need to be used into directive which is what the code above is.

Comment: It will work if the directive will be the only attribute directive used on an element, but http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2729-don-t-blindly-isolate-all-the-scopes-in-angularjs-directives.htm